# Downloadable product on Amazon S3

Tags: url, downloadable, amazon

I'm trying to implement the following scenario:

1. Host downloadable product on AmazonS3
2. Make S3 files private (not accessibile by direct url)
3. Enable access if Referrer is *mywebsite*

If I try to point on a webpage to product url, referrer il trasferred and download start but if I try to buy a product and to use the url autogenerated by magento, I get "not authorized" error from Amazon S3.

I think that the problem is that Referrer header are not set, is there a way to add this to download link?

Edit 28/12:
I tried to debug download url and I have the following result:

```
Request URL:***mydomain***/downloadable/download/link/id/MC41MTUzODgwMCAxNTEzNzYxNDk4MjEzMTg1NjU1Nw,,/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 
Remote Address:*****
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I think that the problem is Referrer Policy. How can I change it? I tried to edit Download.php class as following with no success

```
                $headers = 'GET ' . $path . $query . ' HTTP/1.0' . "\r\n"
                . 'Host: ' . $urlProp['host'] . "\r\n"
                . 'User-Agent: Magento ver/' . Mage::getVersion() . "\r\n"
                . 'Referrer-Policy: origin' . "\r\n"
                . 'Connection: close' . "\r\n"
                . "\r\n";
            fwrite($this->_handle, $headers);
```

Comment: I wonder why you get a Status Code of 302 for the URL above? Where does it redirect to? EDIT: Never mind, just had a look into the controller and you're redirected to /customer/products.

Comment: Which message do you get after redirect? An error occurred while getting the requested content?  Requested link does not exist?

Comment: The error is like "permission denied", I'm not authorized to open that file

Comment: Hey this extension has amazon s3 downloadable products related functionality if you want to take a look
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-amazon-s3.html